# ToUnicode not returning special characters

Tags: vb.net, winapi

Basically I am trying to implement a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook combined with ToUnicode...
I know this may sound stupid.. But I did get it to work, with special characters like: '"#¤%#!*', and so on.. But I was playing around with the code to try and fix accents.. I realized eventually that it wouldn't work (after also reading a lot up on the internet).

So I figured it'd do for now, but when I was reverting back to my old code, it wasn't working anymore..

So the hook itself is working (I am getting key down and up events at least.)

The problem lies in the virtual key -> character conversion, that is in this method:

```
'This is the callback method from the hook
 Private Shared Function Process(Code As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    If Code = 0 Then
        Dim KeyData As KeyData
        KeyData = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, KeyDataType)
        Dim Down As Boolean
        Dim Up As Boolean

        Select Case wParam
            Case 256, 260
                Down = True
            Case 257, 261
                Up = True
        End Select

        If Down Then
            Dim KeyState(255) As Byte
            GetKeyboardState(KeyState)

            Dim Key(0) As Char
            ToUnicode(KeyData.vkCode, KeyData.scanCode, KeyState, Key, 2, KeyData.flags)
            RaiseEvent KeyPress(New KeyPressEventArgs(KeyData.vkCode, Key(0)))
        End If
    End If
    Return CallNextHookEx(0, Code, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```

However the weird it converts and output special characters just fine when the window is in focus...
Please help me :)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The P/Invokes I used: http://pastebin.com/iaL8dfSV

Comment: Everybody always discovers this the Hard Way.  GetKeyboardState() is the problem, that's the keyboard state of your program, not the process that's in the foreground.  Doing this reliably requires a WH_KEYBOARD hook (not _LL).  Very hard to do, you can't write them in managed code.

Comment: But I had it working! Then I changed something because I wanted to test out accents (something I discovered didn't work), changed it back(I do not think the code is exactly the same as it was) and now it's not working anymore.... So it's very frustrating to know, as I did indeed have it working (without having to have the window in focus)!